# Text size is changed when add launch images by xcasset

Tags: ios, xcasset, launchimage

After add launch image follows [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html) then run on iOS 8 and iOS9.
Text size when run app on iOS8 and iOS9 is different. Text size when run on iOS9 seem small than text size on run on iOS8.

Any body have ever meet this bug, please give me the solution? thanks you

Comment: iOS 9 use San Francisco as the default font, where iOS 8 user Helvetica .

Comment: both ios 8 and ios 9 with same device size ?

Comment: yes, both ios 8 and ioS 9 is iPhone 6 Plus device

Comment: This problem only was happened whenever i implement launch images. when i did't use launch images, it wasn't happened.

Comment: @rckoenes thank you so much, reason is the different of default font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 9 use [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) as the default font, where iOS 8 user Helvetica.